# Pandas merge function producing duplicate error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I am still new to pandas and I am having difficulty merging two particular data frames.

The right table looks like this:

[image: Right table]

and the left table looks like this:

[image: Left table]

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
with pd.HDFStore(spadl_h5) as spadlstore:
    games = spadlstore["games"].merge(spadlstore["competitions"], 
                                      left_on='competitionId', right_on='wyId')
```

and this is the error I am receiving:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-98ebcfc55d82> in <module>
      1 with pd.HDFStore(spadl_h5) as spadlstore:
----> 2     games = spadlstore["games"].merge(spadlstore["competitions"], 
      3                                       left_on='competitionId', right_on='wyId')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in merge(self, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
   7282         from pandas.core.reshape.merge import merge
   7283 
-> 7284         return merge(
   7285             self,
   7286             right,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
     71     validate=None,
     72 ) -> "DataFrame":
---> 73     op = _MergeOperation(
     74         left,
     75         right,

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    625             self.right_join_keys,
    626             self.join_names,
--> 627         ) = self._get_merge_keys()
    628 
    629         # validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _get_merge_keys(self)
    994                         right_keys.append(rk)
    995                     if lk is not None:
--> 996                         left_keys.append(left._get_label_or_level_values(lk))
    997                         join_names.append(lk)
    998                     else:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
   1690             values = self.axes[axis].get_level_values(key)._values
   1691         else:
-> 1692             raise KeyError(key)
   1693 
   1694         # Check for duplicates

KeyError: 'competitionId'
```

Both 'left_on' and 'right_on' columns are int64. 
I have also tried every possible version of 'how' (left/right/outer/inner) in merging but I still get the same error.

(The tables are in h5 format as I am attempting to use the socceraction package)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the left and right flipped based on your question?

Try this maybe:

```
with pd.HDFStore(spadl_h5) as spadlstore:
    games = spadlstore["games"].merge(spadlstore["competitions"], 
                                      left_on='wyId', right_on='competitionId')
```

Comment: I don't think so, because the column from the right table (games) is 'competitionId' and the column from the left table (competitions) is wyId. I just want to have the row shown from the left table (competitions) merged with every row where the competitionId is 364 in the right table (games) (i.e. they match on the two columns mentioned above).

Comment: I was just saying based on your question above, your right and left table in question were flipped. Right table was the competitionId and left table was wyId and in your merge you used the reverse

Comment: It would be better if you could paste more of your code and the data directly and not as an image

Comment: I tried to flip the order but still got the same error.

Comment: I got all previous code from this github notebook: https://github.com/ML-KULeuven/socceraction/blob/wyscout_support/public-notebooks/EXTRA-load-and-convert-wyscout-data.ipynb

Comment: After running all that, which ran fine I try to merge the two tables I mentioned earlier with the code I showed. Can't figure out why it's not working though.